# How do I find battery voltage on macOS 13 Ventura?

Tags: battery, ventura

I tried  `system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep Voltage`, but it doesn't seem to have it anymore. Similarly, it is missing from System Information -> Hardware -> Power.

Comment: try the `ioreg -w 0 -f -r -c AppleSmartBattery`

Comment: @Ruskes: No - at least not directly. I get something in a couple of places that says: `"Voltage" = 12192`. I guess we might ***assume*** that is 12.192 volts, but I doubt if Apple has any documentation on this - or do they?

Comment: 12192 mV (milli Volts) = 12.192 Volt

Comment: Yeah, it works. I can use `ioreg -w 0 -f -r -c AppleSmartBattery | grep AppleRawBatteryVoltage` to get just one line of output. But it kind of wastes processing power. Is there a straightforward way to get a specific field from ioreg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a reference for how to make a helper program to get specific fields from the IO registry: (https://github.com/cedowens/ioreg-and-sysctl-examples/blob/main/SystemInfo/SystemInfo/main.swift)

```
import Foundation

let dev = IOServiceMatching("AppleSmartBattery")
let platformExpert : io_service_t = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMainPortDefault, dev)
let keyAsCFString = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, "Voltage" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)
IOObjectRelease(platformExpert)
let result: CFTypeRef = keyAsCFString!.takeUnretainedValue()
print("\(result)")
```

Or just use `CommandLine.arguments[1]` and `CommandLine.arguments[2]` and make a helper program that will output just the value of a particular field from a particular class.